# I need to pass info to a class and then return to the main class in Java

Tags: java, class

```
String menu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'LOGIN', 'REGISTER', or 'EXIT'");
        if (menu.equalsIgnoreCase("login") || menu.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
        {
            String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter your username.");
            String pinS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter your PIN.");

            /* Want to call other class and pass username and pinS
            if (LoginVerification (username, pinS) == 1)
                   loggedIn = true;
            else
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Account/PIN not found/doesn't match.");
            */
        }
```

That is a section of the main class called Startup.java
This is the other class called LoginVerication.java

```
package bankbalance;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginVerification
{
    public void loginVerification (username, pin)
    {
        boolean usernameFound = false, pinMatches = false;
        try
        {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (new FileReader ("accounts.txt"));

            while (fileReader.hasNextLine() && !usernameFound)
            {
                usernameFound = fileReader.nextLine().indexOf(username) >= 0; // want username to be passed from other class
            }
            pinMatches = fileReader.nextLine().indexOf(pin) >= 0; // want pin to be passed from other class

            if (usernameFound && pinMatches)
            {
               return 1; // return 1 to other class
            }

            else
            {
                return 0; // return 0 to other class
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException z)
       {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "No Accounts found. Please register a new account.");
        }

    }
}
```

How do I correctly do this? I want the LoginVerification.java to be called from the Startup.java and then return 1 if the username is found and the pin matches for the username. Thanks!

[Heres the full Startup.java](http://pastebin.com/S8esyTrV)

Comment: make your method return a boolean, and last line be `return usernameFound && pinMatches`

Comment: Can you post your full Startup.java class?

Comment: @Hathor I added it it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LoginVerification {

public static int check(String username, String pin) {
    boolean usernameFound = false, pinMatches = false;
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileReader("accounts.txt"));

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine() && !usernameFound) {
            usernameFound = fileReader.nextLine().indexOf(username) >= 0; // want username to be passed from other class
        }
        pinMatches = fileReader.nextLine().indexOf(pin) >= 0; // want pin to be passed from other class

        if (usernameFound && pinMatches) {
            return 1; // return 1 to other class
        }

        else {
            return 0; // return 0 to other class
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException z) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Accounts found. Please register a new account.");
        return 0;
    }

    }
}
```

and in the calling code :

```
      if (LoginVerification.check (username, pinS) == 1)
               loggedIn = true;
        else
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Account/PIN not found/doesn't match.");
```

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while since I did this so I didn't remember it very clearly. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (LoginVerification.loginVerfication(username, pinS) == 1)
```

This should work. You should make your method `static` since it doesn't seem to rely on any particular instance.